# how to display a webpage in webview on pepper robo tablet

Tags: android, webview, pepper

I am trying to display a webpage in webview on pepper robo tablet.

In an ongoing project html page already created with button. I would like to display "https://www.ebay.com/" webpage in webview when user clicked on button.

it is Robotics platform NAOqi connected with Android tablet pc where user can click buttons through touch.

i have created main.xml file with button and webview tags
created Activity for button onclick
created another Activity for webview.

```
//bill.html page

<table class="billtab">


     <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">

                    <div id="mPay" class="buttonstyle" 
onclick="goToLoginPage();">mPay</div>
                </td>
                <td align="center">                        
                    <div id="ePay" class="buttonstyle" >Pay by ePay</div>                   
                </td>
             </tr>
    </tbody>
        </table>

--------------------------

/main.xml file

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<Button
        android:id="@+id/ePay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Go to https://www.epay.com/"
        />

<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>

------------------------------------

//MainActivity.java

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button button;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Context context = this;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ePay);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
          }
        });
    }
}
------------------------------

//webviewactivity.java

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

            private WebView webView;
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.webview);
            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl("https://www.epay.com/");

    }
}
-------------------------------
```

on pepper robo tablet a webpage should be displayed in webview

Comment: What version of the Robot are you using? Are you using the Android QiSDK or Choregraph?
Do you have to install an Android App on the Tablet or is opening the Website through choregraph/python also an option for you?

Comment: NAOqi version 2.5.10.7 -- i am using choregraph-- i can open the website through choregraph when user clicks on button(using javascript window.open() function). However webpage has to display in webview. Since webview is Android component how to display in pepper android tablet.. please suggest workaround. Thanks

Comment: I think the page is actually already displayed in the webview. In Choregraph you called ALTabletService::showWebview or ShowWebView Box? So page is displayed in Webview already. 
Calling window.open() in that webview will still be webview...
What is yout motivation to use android programming at all? 
With 2.5.10.7. it is not supported and alot can be solved with choregraph/python/javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in NAOqi 2.5 you don't need to do any Android development, you can just do ALTabletService.showWebview for a webpage hosted inside your application. See [using pepper's tablet](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/getting_started/creating_applications/using_peppers_tablet.html) for more documentation on that, and [robot-jumpstarter](https://github.com/aldebaran/robot-jumpstarter) for a couple exaples of doing that.

In your case, you would probably be alternativing between locally hosted pages (i.e. that are part of an app, hosted on Pepper, and contain your buttons), and external pages like ebay.